# Python - Decoding Binary to Boolean

Tags: python, struct, binary, boolean, unpack

I'm trying to receive some data with sockets, and then unpack the data to work on it.

In input, i have a binary string :
"MsgID - Sender - Size - Time1 - Time2 - Resrv - bool1 - bool2"

Here is the format :
"H - H - L - f - I - L - 'bool' - 'bool'"

When I receive the data, I have to unpack it with this line :

```
messageEnaKill = struct.unpack('!HHLfIL??', messageEnaKill_raw)
```

And then I have to work on the boolean values (the last 2 ones).
The fact is I don't know the format for boolean values, is it a char ('c') or something ?

My second problem is that I have to check the binary boolean if it is True or False. How can I do that ?
is this code true :

```
if msg[0] == bin(True):
```

considering "msg[0]" the boolean data from the "unpack".

Thanks for the support !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [struct documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

> The '?' conversion code corresponds to the _Bool type defined by C99. If this type is not available, it is simulated using a char. In standard mode, it is always represented by one byte.

The `?` type will be unpacked as a bool type:

```
>>> type(struct.unpack('?','c')[0])
<type 'bool'>
```

Any value other than null character (`'\0'`) will be True. So you can follow the suggestion from Jan Vlcinsky. Your solution depends on what data you receive. If a null byte means False and other byte True, then you can continue using `?` unpacking as a simplest solution.

So to check if your first boolean in a message is true use this test:

```
messageEnaKill = struct.unpack('!HHLfIL??', messageEnaKill_raw)
if(messageEnaKill[7]==True):
    # do something
```

Comment: Ok, so I keep the line :  

`messageEnaKill = struct.unpack('!HHLfIL??', messageEnaKill_raw)`
And to check if it's true, this should work ? :  

`if msg[0] != 0:`

Comment: updated my answer, not sure if the msg would work i don't know what buffer it is. But if it was the byte that holds the boolean it could work.

Answer (score 1):

You may decide to put multiple bits into one integer and pack/unpack that integer

To convert list of booleans, following functions might be of help:

```
def encode_booleans(bool_lst):
    res = 0
    for i, bval in enumerate(bool_lst):
        res += int(bval) << i
    return res

def decode_booleans(intval, bits):
    res = []
    for bit in xrange(bits):
        mask = 1 << bit
        res.append((intval & mask) == mask)
    return res
```

To test it:

```
>>> blst = [True, False, True]
>>> encode_booleans(blst)
5
>>> decode_booleans(5, 3)
[True, False, True]
>>> decode_booleans(5, 10)
[True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

## Encoding

Encoding is then done in two steps

1. turn set of booleans into an integer
2. create resulting structure to `pack` using all the other types plus newly created integer

## Decoding

Decoding goes also in two steps, just in oposite order

1. unpack into expected structure, booleans being represented s single integer
2. decode the integer into set of booleans

This assumes, you have encoding part under control.

## Full example

Assuming `import struct` was done and the two functions above are defined:

```
>>> packform = "!HHLfILB"
>>> msg_id = 101
>>> sender = 22
>>> size = 1000
>>> time1 = 123.45
>>> time2 = 222
>>> bool1 = True
>>> bool2 = False
>>> bools_enc = encode_booleans([bool1, bool2])
>>> bools_enc
1
>>> resrv = 55
>>> msg_lst = [msg_id, sender, size, time1, time2, resrv, bools_enc]
>>> enc = struct.pack(packform, *msg_lst)
>>> enc
'\x00e\x00\x16\x00\x00\x03\xe8B\xf6\xe6f\x00\x00\x00\xde\x00\x00\x007\x01'
>>> decoded = struct.unpack(packform, enc)
>>> decoded
(101, 22, 1000, 123.44999694824219, 222, 55, 1)
>>> msg_lst
[101, 22, 1000, 123.45, 222, 55, 1]
>>> new_msg_id, new_sender, new_size, new_time1, new_time2, new_resrv, new_bools_enc = decoded
>>> new_bool1, new_bool2 = decode_booleans(new_bools_enc, 2)
>>> new_bool1
True
>>> new_bool2
False
```

Comment: Ok, Are you suggesting encode into integer before sending it ? or after the "unpack" line ? I don't get it

Comment: @tutur29 Added to my answer (the conversion turns into 2 step process)

Comment: Your last line in the response is my problem. I receive the data with a socket with this line :  

`messageEnaKill_raw, adresseEnaKill = connexion.recvfrom(1024)`  

And I know I have boolean data to receive in it, but I don't manage it before.

Comment: @tutur29 In that case is my solution not applicable. I will edit title of your question reversing order to "Binary to boolean". Anyway, it was nice exercise for me with struct (never used that before).

Comment: You're wright,
Anyway thank you for your time @Jan Vlcinsky (this might be useful in other cases)